# After compiling a C program with Eclipse IDE, "Program Compatibiltiy Assistant" shows up

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw

I am coding C programs that use Windows API functions. I am using Eclipse as an IDE, and MingW as a compiler. Whenever I compile something through Eclipse, it functions fine, but after it closes, "Program Compatibility Assistant" shows up and says, "This program might not have installed correctly". This is strange, as when I was using Visual Studio Code as an IDE, and MingW as the compiler, it would run just the same, but without the Program Compatibility Assistant pestering the user afterward. However, I prefer Eclipse as an IDE to VSCode for writing C.

I have tried to compare and contrast linker and build settings, but I am unsure of how to adequately do this in Eclipse.

How can I get the Program Compatibility Assistant to no longer pop-up after running a newly built C program?

Comment: Does your program have "install" or "setup" in the name?

Comment: @user253751 No, it is just a simple program. It is not meant to install anything.

Comment: but does it have one of these words in the name?

Comment: @user253751 No. None of those words are in the name.